# Launch local executable from greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, local-files

Below is the code I am trying (plus a few variations), there is a dialog asking for my permission, but still errors out with

> Error: Permission denied for  to get property XPCComponents.classes

```
unsafeWindow.netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect'); 

var file = unsafeWindow.Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("d:\\test.bat");

var process = unsafeWindow.Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

var args = ["argument1", "argument2"];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Is this just going to be impossible?

Comment: I guess I should add that I'm currently testing this with FF 3.6.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. See [Do Greasemonkey scripts have chrome privileges?](http://wiki.greasespot.net/FAQ#Do_Greasemonkey_scripts_have_chrome_privileges.3F).

Comment: haha, guess I should have just read the FAQ. I've actually been reading about FF4 and Jetpack which seems like a viable alternative.

Answer (score 10):

@Jano answer is right, but you can still invoke the `.bat` file using a custom protocol handler such as `myprotocol://parameters`. Also explained here: [How to run local program (exe) via Chrome via HTML/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415841/how-to-run-local-program-exe-via-chrome-via-html-javascript]])

Adding this keys to your registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myprotocol
      (Default) = "URL:Test Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "d:\test.bat" "%1"
```

And inside the .bat to capture the parameter:

```
set param=%1
echo Parameter is "%param:~13,100%
```

Where `:~13,100` Crops the first 13 characters of the parameter (`myprotocol://`)

Then in your script just use the custom protocol URL on `window.location`, `$.ajax` or assign to an `<a>`'s `href`.

Comment: A protocol for Microsoft Edge exists. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31281412/97799