# How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I need to open URL in Microsoft Edge (on Windows 10). When I invoke

```
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge http://www.google.com
```

then Microsoft Edge is started correctly but it doesn't open the given URL (www.google.com, in this case). It opens Bing search where the given URL is used as a search term instead.

Comment: I just tested your command above in PowerShell and it correctly opened google.com for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My command really works in PowerShell. I tried it in Command Prompt (cmd) before (where it opens Bing search as I mentioned). I am really confused why the behaviour is different in cmd and PowerShell but I am fine with running the command through PowerShell.

Comment: If it's not working for some reason check your quotes. I had an issue with `explorer "microsoft-edge:https://www.example.com/foo?querystring=yes"` when not using quotes (though using `start` I didn't have any issue, either way).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The following method should work via Command Prompt (cmd):

```
start microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com
```

Comment: How did you even figure that out? seriously! I would not have ever tried that.. (works on Windows 10 Edge)

Comment: How would you launch it from c#? Thanks.

Comment: @wasatchwizard: see [How to script Microsoft's Edge browser](http://www.itworld.com/article/2943955/windows/how-to-script-microsofts-edge-browser.html)

Comment: This is great, but does anyone have any idea how this technique was worked out? It would be great to have it confirmed by MS somewhere, to know it is reasonably future-proof, but I can't find anything  ...

Comment: The problem I run into is that you have to specify the protocol (http:// or https://) or it won't work. This is not ideal for me. I would like to be able to open a site using www.mysite.com

Comment: `start` here is just a particular command. It is similar to "Run" dialog.

Comment: any ideas how to get the http response from edge for the given request?

Comment: @FruitBreak, a little late here, but this works because capable url associations (launchable protocols) for Microsoft-Edge include the following: `http`, `https`, `microsoft-edge`, and `read`. The particular protocol in question, `Microsoft-Edge`, is specific to Edge, while others are subject to default app settings ("choose default apps by protocol"). If edge is your default app for the `read` protocol, then you can launch it by typing the following in file explorer `read:http://www.cnn.com`. `http` and `https` can be set as seperate protocols or together by the default web browser.

Comment: There may also be other protocols supports by different versions of Edge, like `microsoft-edge-holographic`

Comment: This only works for relatively short URLs.  Any URL longer than 245 characters is truncated.  Here's a sample command line you can try: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c explorer "microsoft-edge:https://www.garbage.com/?signature=012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"

Comment: It turns out that using CMD there are URL length limitations, but using PowerShell there aren't (or at least the long URLs I tried worked).  However, PowerShell may not run from the command line on a stock Windows without changing security settings.  Example: PowerShell "start microsoft-edge:http://stackoverflow.com"

Comment: The `file:` scheme is not supported!

Comment: for `file:\\\ ` protocol [see the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731977/1951524).

Comment: It won't work when working with url having get params
`start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge http://localhost:8080/sample?a&b=1`

Comment: How to open a specific profile of Edge using shell script ?

Comment: Is there any way to mention a specific profile?

Comment: If you have thew new Chromium-based edge, you can simply call the exe and pass an **absolute** path to the file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150382/1048186). Example from Git Bash with `$i` holding the full filename: `start msedge $(cygpath -wa $(pwd)/$i);`

Answer (score 11):

Windows 10: Create a shortcut with this destination:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "start microsoft-edge:https://twitter.com"
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to use the quotes there. So if you need to use a program-parameters string syntax then you can use `"c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe"` as a program and `"/c start microsoft-edge:%u"` as a parameter string.

Answer (score 11):

All the other solutions work for Microsoft Edge (legacy) and on Windows 10 only.

As of 2020, it will be discontinued and replaced by Microsoft Edge (Chromium based).

The solution that works with the new Edge on Windows 7, 8 and 10 is :

```
start msedge URL
```

Source:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Anaheim_(2019%E2%80%93present)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-sysupdate-windows-updates

Comment: I tried several things, but this solution finally helped. thank you @Baptistou

Answer (score 9):

and a shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge http://localhost:6516
```

Comment: this is the only way that also supports the `file:///` protocol for opening local files.

Comment: It doesn't work if url is `http://localhost:6516/sample?x=1&y=2` it results `http://localhost:6516/sample?x` which is wrong

Comment: @ArchisThakkar The ampersand sign (&) cannot be used in middle of the command in the command line. Try this instead `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge "http://localhost:6516/sample?x=1&y=2"`

Comment: The above didn't work as double-quotes were not escaping.

This worked for me 
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge http://localhost:6516/sample?x=1^&y=2`

Answer (score 7):

I too was wondering why you can't just start microsoftedge.exe, like you do "old-style" applications in windows 10.  Searching the web, I found the answer -- it has to do with how Microsoft implemented "Universal Apps".

Below is a brief summary taken from that answer, but I recommend reading the entire entry, because it gives a great explanation of how these "Universal Apps" are being dealt with.  Microsoft Edge is not the only app like this we'll be dealing with.

Here's the link: http://www.itworld.com/article/2943955/windows/how-to-script-microsofts-edge-browser.html

Here's the summary from that page:

"Microsoft Edge is a "Modern" Universal app. This means it can't be opened from the command line in the traditional Windows manner:  Executable name followed by command switches/parameter values. But where there's a will, there's a way. In this case, the "way" is known as protocol activation."

Kudos to the author of the article, Stephen Glasskeys.

Comment: in fall creators update 1709 which will be released soon, store apps allow commandline + parameters

Answer (score 6):

While the accepted answer is correct, it has the unwanted artifact of flashing a console window when running from a non-console application.

The solution I found works best, which is only mentioned here in a [comments to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line/58840422#comment92496244_31164253), is the following command line:

```
explorer.exe "microsoft-edge:<URL>"
```

Keep in mind that if  contains the `%` sign you will need to type `%%` as Windows uses the symbol for variable expansion.

Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use this function which I created and put in my profile script `...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\….profile`, feel free to use it. As I am from the UK, I prefer to go to `.co.uk` where possible, if you are from another area, you can add your own country code.

```
# Function taking parameter add (address) and opens in edge.
Function edge {
    param($add)
    if (-not ($add -contains "https://www." -or $add -contains "http://www.")) {
        if ($add[0] -eq "w" -and $add[1] -eq "w" -and $add[2] -eq "w") {
            $add = "https://" + $add
        } else {
            $add = "https://www." + $add
        }
    }

    # If no domain, tries to add .co.uk, if fails uses .com
    if (-not ($add -match ".co" -or $add -match ".uk" -or $add -match ".com")) {
        try {
            $test = $add + ".co.uk"
            $HTTP_Request  = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($test)
            $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
            $add = $add + ".co.uk"
        } catch{
            $add = $add + ".com"
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Taking you to $add"
    start microsoft-edge:$add
}
```

Then you just have to call: `edge google` in powershell to go to `https://www.google.co.uk`

Comment: Upvoted since this solution does not suffer from the long URL limitation of the other solutions using CMD.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like things have changed and the previous solution doesn't work anymore.

However, here is the working command to launch CNN.com on Microsoft Edge:

```
microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend:
Microsoft Edge Run Wrapper
https://github.com/mihula/RunEdge

You run it this way:

```
RunEdge.exe [URL]
```

- where URL may or may not contains protocol (http://), when not provided, wrapper adds http://
- if URL not provided at all, it just opens edge

Examples:

```
RunEdge.exe http://google.com
RunEdge.exe www.stackoverflow.com
```

It is not exactly new way how to do it, but it is wrapped as exe file, which could be useful in some situations. For me it is way how to start Edge from IBM Notes Basic client.

Comment: I think this is quite a bit simpler: microsoft-edge:[URL]  Does that not work in your case?

Comment: That project seems pointless to me. Why not just run microsoft-edge:[URL] like @TheEmirOfGroofunkistan said?

Comment: See above, unfortunately this program has the same problem as the accepted solution.  It only works for URLs shorter than 245 characters.

Comment: Also see above, but if RunEdge was changed to use PowerShell instead of CMD it would work for longer URLs.

Comment: there is a similar "offical" project: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/edge-launcher

Answer (score 3):

I want to complement other answers here in regards to opening a blank tab in Microsoft Edge from command-line.

I want to add an observation from my end. Windows doesn't detect the command `microsoft-edge` if I remove the trailing colon. I thought colon would be required only when I've to provide the target URL to open e.g. when I've to open a blank tab. But that's not the case. Color (`:`) is required all the time.

**How to open a blank tab in Microsoft Edge?**

- From **Run** prompt (press <kbd>Window logo</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>):

  ```
  microsoft-edge:about:blank
  microsoft-edge:
  msedge
  ```
- From **Command**(cmd.exe) prompt:

  ```
  start microsoft-edge:about:blank
  start microsoft-edge:
  start msedge
  ```

You can also initiate a search using Edge from run prompt. Let's say I've to search `Barack Obama` then fire below command on run prompt-

```
microsoft-edge:Barack Obama
```

It starts Microsoft's Bing search website in Edge with `Barack Obama` as search term.

Comment: How do I open the New Tab page instead of a blank page?
`start microsoft-edge:about:newtab` does not seem to work as it opens Edge with the default search engine and `about:newtab` as a search term only.

Answer (score 0):

It will do more or less the same thing in good old dos script fashion

```
set add=%1
if %add%$ ==$ set add="about:blank" && goto launch

rem http://
set test=%add:~0, 7%
if %test% == http:// goto launch

rem ftp:// 
set test=%add:~0, 6%
if %test% == ftp:// goto launch

rem https://
set test=%add:~0, 8%
if %test% == https:// goto launch

rem add http
set add=http://%add%

:launch
start microsoft-edge:%add%
```

Answer (score 0):

`microsoft-edge:http://google.com` (open google as desired)
`microsoft-edge:` (just open)