# Launching Microsoft Edge with URL from code

Tags: c#, browser, microsoft-edge

I need to launch the Microsoft Edge browser with a specific URL from a c# application. How can I do that? What's the best way to retrieve the path where Microsoft Edge is installed and call it passing the appropriate arguments?
I would like to launch it directly without installing any webdriver.

I saw this [How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line) but couldn't make it work from code.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 6):

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.yourpage.co.uk");
```

Comment: or even just Process.Start("microsoft-edge:")

Answer (score 3):

I figured that out.

You can call the browser by using `microsoft-edge:http://www.yoursite.com` from the command line.

Comment: How do I open the New Tab page instead of a web page? `start microsoft-edge:about:newtab` does not seem to work as it opens Edge with the default search engine and `about:newtab` as a search term only.