# Sublime Text 3 Microsoft Edge Build System

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, microsoft-edge, sublime-build

so normally you can use the following to create a Build System:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe","$file"]
}
```

With edge, however, you can't simply start it up by double clicking the .exe found at the path

```
C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Which means this doesn't work (i tried this):

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Windows\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\MicrosoftEdge.exe","$file"]
}
```

Is there a way to create a Sublime Text Build System so that when you hit Ctrl+B the file opens up in Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out finally:

```
{
    "cmd": ["explorer.exe", "microsoft-edge:$file"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31164253/1426065)):

```js
{
    "cmd": ["start microsoft-edge:file:///$file"]
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have Windows 10 handy to test this, but from the above link and other Google results this should be the way to go.

Comment: Command works in a command prompt but not when i run it from sublime.  get the following error: 
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['start microsoft-edge:D:\\Dev\\Js\\Example\\eventHandler.html']]

Comment: @DavidTorrey try my edit above - maybe you need to include the `file:///` protocol for a local file...

Comment: no dice, doesn't even work if i try to point it to a website instead of a file

Comment: for some reason it's having an issue finding microsoft-edge

Comment: @DavidTorrey how about changing `"cmd"` to `"shell_cmd"`. Does that help?

Comment: doesn't even run in that case.  I'm playing around with the actual .exe to see if i can't get it to do something.  makes no sense to me they'd have an exe i can't execute but hey, what do I know

Comment: had to run it as a parameter of explorer.exe