# How to launch Microsoft Edge (with no address bar if possible) from a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been trying to write a script in which I want to launch a web app in Microsoft Edge specifically (if it is installed). But executing the `.exe` file doesn't seem to work.

The path that I've found for Edge on my computer, using the task manager as the reference, seems to be `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe`. This part seems a bit arbitrary, as `8wekyb3d8bbwe` in the folder name doesn't really seem like a constant. On another computer, this would probably be different? Furthermore, when I navigate to that folder, and double click `MicrosoftEdge.exe` or `MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe`, nothing happens.

For comparison I've tried Firefox's `.exe` file, and it executes properly from the script by doing:

```
START "Web App" "%programfiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -chrome http://www.example.com/app
```

Additionally, if possible, can Microsoft Edge be launched without the address bar and the tabs? It's the equivalent to running Firefox with the `-chrome` parameter, and Google Chrome with the `--app` parameter.

Comment: Googling shows [How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31164253) Can't say anything about the no-bar mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm That looks promising, but as I don't have the path to the executable file, how would one check if it exists/is installed before invoking?

Comment: Well, I don't have Windows 10 so I can only suggest googling or the obvious check for the windows version via `for /f` and `ver`.

Comment: I would assume it is the same switch that Internet Explorer used.  `-K`

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
msedge.exe --kiosk https://google.com/ --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --no-first-run
```

You can find more information about Edge and kiosk mode:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode