# How to launch Microsoft Edge browser with gulp-open?

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, microsoft-edge

Currently using the NPM package [`gulp-open`](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-open) to open the desired browser via gulp. It is working for chrome, firefox and internet explorer, however not with the Microsoft Edge browser.

**My gulp task:**

```
return gulp.src(base.app)
    .pipe(open({
        uri: 'localhost/' + cwd + "/app/" + path_base,
        app: browser // chrome, iexplore, firefox
}));
```

I have tried with the following for the edge browser `MicrosoftEdge`, `edge`, `Edge`, `microsoft-edge`. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you can't even open the edge browser from the system with a double click?

Edge can be found on the file system here: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe

Running it via the CLI also works like this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line)):

```
$ start microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com
```

How to open it via the `gulp-open` package?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this myself, and I got the answer from the author [stevelacy](https://github.com/stevelacy)

You can see in the [issue](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-open/issues/29)

As he says you can open any program as long as it is listed in the PATH. The IE worked for me as 'iexplore'.

You can find more info in this thread. https://superuser.com/questions/113345/how-to-launch-internet-explorer-from-the-command-prompt

The answer comes late, but I hope it is useful to some visitor.
cheers