# Issues with opening edge with powershell

Tags: powershell

When I open edge up in powershell writing "start microsoft-edge:" It puts the following in front of the url I try to open: "--disable-quic --edge-redirect=Windows.Protocol microsoft-edge:". Does anybody know how to fix this so it opens up the correct homepage?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset your default app setting to microsoft defaults.

Comment: I wasn't using powershell, just clicking on links in Outlook, and facing the same problem. Your answer fix my issue as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when using a batch file, but the code "start microsoft-edge" may depend on your operating system and the version of Microsoft Edge you have. Specifically, newer versions of Microsoft Edge may require slightly different commands to open a URL via the command line.

You can try modifying "start microsoft-edge:%URL%" to "start msedge %URL%". This is because in some versions of Windows and Microsoft Edge, "msedge" is the correct command to open the browser.