# How to run local program (exe) via Chrome via HTML/javascript

Tags: google-chrome, local-files

I am trying to build a (single page) local portal in Chrome that opens several things.

The problem is we want to run a local executable via a button on a (local) webpage. Is this possible?

The second thing is that i want to do is to run a .pps file directly in the powerpoint viewer.

I can control to the startup of chrome, so i can access local files.

All things i tried so far only made the file(s) to download, not to run.

Can somebody help me how i get this done?

Comment: Running an exe file from a website would be a major security flaw. I doubt it is possible. Perhaps it is possible to do so through a chrome extension however.

Comment: Security is not an issue. The webapp runs local without internet conncection.

Comment: It is for a web browser, which is why a browser would not typically allow it. If your website is offline, why run it through a browser instead of making an app with nodejs for instance ?

Comment: because a single installation is always cheaper than maintaining 500 client installations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set a protocol like myapp://launch/activity or the like to automatically launch your app by setting up a registry key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with the name of your protocol and the action it should take.

There is a [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) showing the following example of a registry for an alert protocol:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Which would then be called by requesting a url with `alert:YOURPARAMS`, which would then call `alert.exe YOURPARAMS`.

Comment: @AlainVanderbroeck Does this solution work on Chrome/Firefox ?

Comment: Yeah.  Chrome and firefox will ask you to approve the app that is being called

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond It works in IE but not in chrome. Has anything changed since you answered?

Comment: @Marc Seems like there is an untriaged bug in the chromium bug tracker Last updated (Jan 4, 2021): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162605&q=custom%20protocol&can=2#c0

Comment: is it possible to interact with the web page? - that is send data back from exe to Javascript?