# How to run windows .exe application from javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

I have a site and windows application and want to run my .exe app from my site when click button. It is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running .exe from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript)

Comment: Run on a client or on a server? :)

Comment: [How to run .exe file or .bat file based on button click event using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104713/how-to-run-exe-file-or-bat-file-based-on-button-click-event-using-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @pc_coder it is not working on chrome, firefox and opera

Comment: @YuryTarabanko on client

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич You can run it just on the client with HTA and not with HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out:

[How to run local program (exe) via Chrome via HTML/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415841/how-to-run-local-program-exe-via-chrome-via-html-javascript)

lets take for example zoom app:

this is the windows registry: [registry imag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKUVk.png)
you can see the windows registry by typing reg in windows search.
there open the "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" by clicking the arrow next to it,
and then look for "zoommtg", and you will get working example that you can examine!

and this is the zoom webpage to launch the zoom app:
[zoom webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afSK0.png)

Comment: I don't understand how this works. How I can call created URI from js? For example, I tried to call Zoom URI and it does not work.

Comment: you can run it from js if it was created let us say when you installed zoom app for example! as far as i know you can not write to the registry from browser js. in the past you could but it is not supported anymore.