# Call windows exe from javascript under windows 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, activexobject, windows-11

I want to call a local exe in Windows from my local HTML page (via JavaScript).
All the years I used ActiveXObjects like:

```
myObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" ); function RunCTG(wiNumber) { filename = "\"D:\\Tools\\MyTool.exe\""+" -WINumber="+wiNumber;

myObject.Run(filename);
```

ActiveXObjects work only in Internet Explorer - thus I have to use IE for this task. Ok.
But since Windows 11, there is no IE anymore.

Are there other ways, to call a Windows exe from a local JavaScript?

Comment: [Probably not](https://www.google.com/search?q=call+a+Windows+exe+from+a+local+JavaScript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan `s/Probably/Hopefully/`

Comment: Do you limit JavaScript executed in Browser? If you consider NodeJs, it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179114/execute-powershell-script-from-node-js

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript, I think the only way is to register a custom protocol URI Scheme like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415841/how-to-run-local-program-exe-via-chrome-via-html-javascript/37416124#37416124). But you need to edit the registry on every machine needs to run the JavaScript.